# Help with jQuery mouseover accordian

Tags: jquery

http://www.blazewebstudio.co.za/Network_2/index.html please help me with the j-query problems on the top horizontal and the side vertical accordion, it bounces and the overflow is out of whack. Also the menu is sometimes strange if you go over it too fast, I Know too many problems but please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#accordion").accordion({event: "mouseover" });
```

Answer (score 2):

You might look in to using the [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#mouseover) might work a little better for you.